# Whats the scope of activeMQ producers, Consumers, Sessions, Connection

Tags: activemq-classic

What is the scope of the following ActiveMQ objects in an application.

1. Connection (is it one per application?)
2. Session (one per application?)
3. Producers
4. Consumers

Am designing an application that will send a lot of messages and I need to know if I can use one of connection, session, producer, consumer in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these depend on various settings, the concepts are summarized well on this page...

http://web.archive.org/web/20120704235809/http://fusesource.com/wiki/display/ProdInfo/Understanding+the+Threads+Allocated+in+ActiveMQ